# Mass production of bacteria

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology, reproduction, cell-culture, biotechnology

Is there a way to mass produce a certain species of bacteria?

Answers I am looking for should not involve a Petri dish: I am only interested in protocols involving, perhaps, more efficient mediums to grow the bacterium-in-question.

Is it done with any yet? In a factory or where etc?

How is it done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [fed batch culture](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fed-batch_culture?wprov=sfla1) is a means of bacterial production that is used in industrial setups. Nutrients are fed into the chamber with controlled ideal conditions for growth of a particular species of microorganisms.

Upon reaching the desired yield temperatures can be increased (depending on the species of bacteria) to facilitate spore formation for eventual harvesting.